# How to pass props from component to navigator in header in react navigation 6 (or > 5)?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I want my header icon to show count (every unread notification is count ++). From my Notification component I want to pass to the header in my Navigator a prop with the count number. All I can find so far are solutions for react navigation <5 (setParams and the like doesnt work with >5) and I am using 6. How do I do it?

```
const App = () => {
    const [notifications, setNotifications] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        const notifications = await API.fetch();
        let count= 0;
        notifications.map(notification => {
            if (notification.isRead === false) count ++;
        })
        // ---> send count to header in Navigator to be shown
        
    }, [])
}
```

```
const MyTabs = (props) => {
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    return (
        <Tab.Navigator
            screenOptions={{
                headerRight: (props) => {
                    return (
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Notifications")}>
                            <Ionicons name="notifications" size={24} color="black"/>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    )}
            }}
        >           
        </Tab.Navigator>
    );
}
```

Edit:

```
const MyStack = () => {
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    return (
        <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Group>
                <Stack.Screen name="Tabs" options={({route}) => ({
                    headerShown: false,
                })}>
                    {(props) => <MyTabs {...props}  />}
                </Stack.Screen>

                <Stack.Screen
                    name="Notifications"
                    options={{
                        headerShown: true, headerLeft: () => (
                    <Button onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} title="go back"
                            />
                        ),
                    }}>
                    {(props) => <NotificationsScreen {...props}/>}
                </Stack.Screen>
            </Stack.Group>

      </Stack.Navigator>
```

```
 <NavigationContainer>
    <MyStack />
 </NavigationContainer>

//NavigationContainer is rendered inside App
```

Comment: Can you show where `MyTabs` gets rendered in relation to `App`? Is `MyTabs` a child of `App`?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is using the `Navigation State` through the [`useNavigationState()` hook](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation-state).

Look at that documentation, specifically at [this section about triggering a re-render](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation-state#how-is-usenavigationstate-different-from-navigationgetstate). You could send that information when you call the `navigation.navigate()`.

Nevertheless, **this is probably the wrong way of doing this**. Using the navigation state to store your app information not related to the navigation is not safe (**and even maybe an anti-pattern**).

There are better ways of sharing a state over different components across your app and you could use one of them. **I suggest using ContextAPI for decoupling the state** from your components for this case as **Redux** is almost overkill.

For an even simpler approach, you could use a derived state from your `notifications` such as:

```
const App = () => {
    const [notifications, setNotifications] = useState([]);
    const [unreadNotificationsCount, setUnreadNotificationsCount] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        const notifications = await API.fetch();
        const newUnreadNotifications = notifications.filter((notification) => !notification.isRead);
        setUnreadNotificationsCount(newUnreadNotifications.length)
    }, []);

    return (
      <>
        <Header unreadNotifications={unreadNotificationsCount} />
      </>
    );
}
```

Also, there are other things that you could take care of:

- fetching data inside `useEffect` is not considered a good pattern. You could call it outside of the `useEffect`.
- `Array.map()` is used to transform one array into another with the same size. If you just want to iterate over, use the `Array.forEach()`
- you made a comment about "sending" the `count` to the Header. React is a "Reactive" framework. If you change that data into a state, all places that depend on that state will update. You can have that with some "global state" lib such as Redux or with ContextAPI (that is inside React)

Comment: Hey @juliascoding, have you had a chance to look at this answer? Need any additional information? After seeing your updates on your question I really recommend you use ContextAPI to control the state you want to share between components on different levels.